# Select an approach to localize large .NET applications

Tags: .net, winforms, localization, gettext

I know that Question of Localizing .NET applications asked here many times.

But I am doubt about effectiveness of the approach to use Resources and 3-d party resource editing tools to localizing large .NET applications.

I am thinking about staying with one of the below approaches:

1. Set Localizable=True for all solution forms, and use 3-d party resource editor, for ex: Zeta Resource Editor, to edit and manage resources.
   Disadvantages:

   - Our solution has ~100 forms, and for 30 extra languages there will be 30*100 = 3000 new resx files!
   - A lot of efforts to interact with translators: I need to send them excel files with plain text after each product update and manually update project resources after each language changes.
   - Part (most?) of the language files will be always outdated, because translators might do their works after product release, and we can't include their changes without recompiling the project.
2. Use custom Dictionary based class (like GNU GetText), that will load an old-fashioned ini file with translations.
   Disadvantage: need to do an extra job, like writing a helper tool to edit ini files for translators.
   Advantage: new language versions might be published after product release as a separate ini files.

Unfortunately I can't compare performance of the both ways.

**Which approach is better? Please share your experience!**

Answer (score 2):

You really should stick with the standard .NET localization system (`ResourceManager`).

One way to deal with the problems you are having (managing imports of a lot of .resx files in various languages into your solution, dealing with delays in the delivery of translations) would be to include just one language (English, typically) in your solution but keep localization enabled.  So from now on you would build your solution with only English resources, but still with the ability to load satellite assemblies if present.

Then you can set up a different project (call it a localization project) for the sole purpose of managing the translation of your English resources into various languages. You'd have to regularly sync the English resx files from your main solution to your localization project (but then this allows you to do so in a controlled manner, which will help dealing with translators). Translations you receive would be checked into this project's source control system.

Then you'll need to write someting to build your satellite assemblies from your localization project and drop them into your English-only build, giving you a  build with all its localizations. Building satellite assemblies from resx files can be done using [Resgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (to create .resources files) and then [Al.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht.aspx) (to create the dll files).

Comment: Sébastien, thanks a lot for the suggestion to not reinvent the wheel. I will stick with ResourceManager and with a third party localization tool. I found that Sisulizer is an excellent tool that covers most of my needs, except automatic translation of the Hard Coded Strings to Resources files. I'll evaluate ReSharper for this purposes.

Anders, thanks for your participation in discussion also.

Answer (score 1):

We use a large excel file with keys in the first column, and one column per language. A little script in the excel document spits out the necessary resx files (one per language), these resx files are then checked into the source tree.

Only the translation assembly will have satellite assemblies, and handles the translations for the entire application. So all other assemblies (UI etc.) will have no satellite assemblies.

In forms we use the keys as texts (for labels, buttons, captions) and recursively translate the forms when shown. For non-control texts we just use a single static class to fetch the translated text given a resource key with code.

This "single file" translation database works very well, and using excel is convenient since your translators probably will already have it installed and are familiar with it.

Comment: Hi Anders and Sébastien! Thanks for your answers! 
When a new version releases - how translators can see new untranslated lines? In case of the ini file I can write a tool to compare english.ini and japanese.ini, and highlight new strings. 

Also does it possible to take a look at your excel script?

Comment: In the excel sheet, we have conditional highlighting to show cells that need filling in (i.e. rows with a translation key but missing the translated value in that column).

Comment: There are localization and CAT (computer-aided translation) tools out there that import/export .resx files and help with updates (obviously, when English content is added or changed, the translations have to be updated) and also that help automatically recycle translated content (if there is repetition, the tool finds previous matches, meaning less work for the translator, less money spent by you, and better quality as this improves consistency). Therefore rolling our your own system is not a good idea--localization tools handle native formats such as .resx

Comment: I think the whole idea of satellite assemblies per assembly and resx file per form quite cumbersome to begin with. Most tools assume the application uses this standard setup. Having to purchase and distribute localization tools to dozens of translators is a lot more work than just sending the whole thing in a single file for an application they already have. Redundancy checking in translations is trivial if it is a single file. I'm not saying the tools are bad once you have them in place. But if it is more difficult than an excel sheet in an email, then they have to be free and excellent.

Comment: I'm the author of a professional localization product (in the interest of full disclosure). I'm not here to promote my app, just to point out that relying on Excel doesn't deal with many important issues, like ensuring your translator properly includes all composite formatting items in any translated string (e.g., "{0}"). There are other validation issues as well. There's also the matter of tracking strings that are changed in your solution, since their translations then need updating. A dedicated app is really required, whether my own, a competitor's, or one you can find for free.

Comment: "There's also the matter of tracking strings that are changed in your solution, since their translations then need updating", if there is a change in semantics, then it is a new lookup key, otherwise not. Duplicate checking, placeholder checking etc. is trivial regardless of how it is performed. I'm not saying a dedicated tool is bad, just that it *really* needs to pull its own weight by bringing features to the table that aren't trivially implemented by a simple script. For example, if a tool could track *unused* resources (that should be removed) that would be a very desirable feature.

Comment: To be clear: the excel sheet *is* a dedicated app, since it all the logic (duplicate checking, placeholder checking, etc) takes place inside the document. I should also add that determining that a translation lookup key is unused is (nearly) impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't want to get off-topic here of course, but no script that does what needs to be done is simple or trivial by any reasonable definition. The issues involved are far too extensive. The cost of writing even the most trivial script would far exceed the cost of purchasing a full-blown translation app. And that app would almost certainly do far more than a script will (even referring to essential features only).