# Good .NET Localization Utility

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, localization

I am looking for a good localization utility for my WPF/WinForms .NET application.

I would like it to be able to reflect through my Resx/Resource files in my compiled application and give me a grid UI to be able to translate from default resx values into the language of my choosing. I would like to to then generate the corresponding .resource files and place them in the right directories. It would be nice if it would refresh or restart my application so that I could see the translated values.

There have to be plenty of utilities already out there that do this, right?

Comment: Visual Studio is the tool you should use.  Here is a similar question with some very good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251225/proper-localization-of-a-winforms-application?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536784/select-an-approach-to-localize-large-net-applications?rq=1 is another thread you might want to look at.  Going to avoid giving specific examples of tools you could use since your exact needs are unknown.

Comment: If you are looking for WPF localization, take a look into http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

I use Simple Resx Editor: http://simpleresxeditor.blogspot.dk/

It's simple and sleek, and you don't need to have visual studio installed.